# Chrome Extensions API and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to put together an extension that logs me out from a web site after some minutes of inactivity.

The idea I had in mind was just to make an http request from the extension to the same url that gets called when clicking the logout link on the webpage.

To do that from Javascript I am using XMLHttpRequest class. The request goes through ok, I can also print the responseText. At a glance by looking at the html it contains the blank form people have to use to log in, which makes sense!

Now if I go back to the web and refresh the page I'd expect to be logged out, well I am not.

Copying and pasting the same logout url I am calling from JS effectively kicks me out!

Comment: Can't help without code, can we? Also, consider using an alternative approach of clearing cookies with `chrome.cookies` API.

Comment: Also, if the website uses some sort of session ID not stored in a cookie, then you won't be able to log out this way.

Comment: Well I am not a  student :) I am also using cookies, creating one of my own to keep track of when some traffic was last seen through that page. Thing is I don't want to mess around with cookie set by that page, as they mught contain stuff I am not aware of.

Comment: I'd examine site's js event handler for the logout link to see what it does.

Comment: Instead of invoking the logout URL, could you create / simulate a click event on the logout button / anchor?

Comment: I am now opening a tab with that url, obviously it works. I can't seem to able to close it though ;)

Comment: Other solution could hav been to open an Iframe with the extension, of course the siste i am connecting to does not allow it!